# Jquery and Css and math: dots in a circle to converge in one point

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a circle of dots in the middle of a web page
i'd like expand the circle and collapse to a certain point sliding a scrubber like a zoom slider

i'm trying to do it via css and jquery, i was also thinking of using webkit transformazion on plane Z but my basic problem is just to move hose dots form a position to another, to converge in one point and back, just sliding the scrubber

do you have an idea of the direction to take?
thanks

Comment: What does your current HTML/CSS/JS look like?

Comment: is not much about my code, i just need an idea how to handle this problem of if there is any example out there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yahooo api are the answer, i solved it

Answer (score 0):

This might be too high-level, but I'd begin by making the position of each dot interpreted as a function of y = m(x)+b just like [point-slope](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/strtlneq.htm) form in algebra. I'm interested in the application and would like to see if I can help more! Try and get started with that and see where it takes you.